# Lazy list loading with image and text in ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I want to create lazy loading list with image and text. For each row of list, Image could be downloaded from server as separate http request. Please let me know if any caching is required for image download. Please let me know any sample for lazy loading list in ionic2.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code for list

```
<ion-list no-lines [virtualScroll]="partnerArray">
<ion-item-sliding *virtualItem="let item; let i=index">
  <ion-item (click)="view(i)">
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <ion-img class="image" src="data:image/*;base64,{{item.imageUrl}}" style="height: 50px; width: 50px"></ion-img>
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
    <p>{{item.email}}</p>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options>
    <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="delete(i)">
      Delete
    </button>
  </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

and in `.ts` file

```
private partnerArray: Array<{
id: number
imageUrl: string,
name: string,
email: string
}> = []

 this.odooRpc.searchRead(this.partner,
 this.domain, this.fields, this.limit, this.offset,
 this.sort).then((partner: any) => {
   let json = JSON.parse(partners._body)["result"].records;
   for (let i in json) {
   this.partnerArray.push({
   id: json[i].id,
   imageUrl: json[i].image_small == false ? "N/A":json[i].image_small ,
   name: json[i].name == false ? "N/A" : json[i].name,
   email: json[i].email == false ? "N/A" : json[i].email
 })

}
})
```

This is a code for odoo server. and i have fetch a record from the odoo server.
Hope it helps you

Comment: I think json[i].image_small is base64 format string. This base64 format image needs to be downloaded separately from http URL. Image will be downloaded and then converted to base64 format. Whether it will require any caching like store each image in a file?

Comment: If you need the offline support, of course you need to save it into file. Otherwise the base64 string will directly show into the `<ion-img>` tag.

Comment: I have added items to an array as follows: this.mainArray.push({PNumber: responseData[i].PNumber, ImagePhoto: this.download(i), Id:responseData[i].Id,});                                                                                                                         where, download method will fetch image from server and convert to base64 format and then return the result to mainArray.ImagePhoto as follows: download(index) { this.getPhotoService.getImagePhoto(ID,(data) => { this.mainArray[index].ImagePhoto=data;return data;  }, (errData) => { return ""; }); Let me know the problem.

Comment: Will it download the image and display for every row in list. Can it map index "i" in download for every row. I get "undefined" value for ImagePhoto and it doesn't display. It is because still image was in download state and yet to complete its download. Once, download completed then list is not getting refreshed with image data.

Comment: You have a url in JSON data or base64 string image ?

Comment: if you uses a Base64 plugin for converting the image then the code for convert is like this   download(imagePath) { this.base64.encodeFile(imagePath).then((base64String: string) => {
          // console.log("-----base64String-----" + base64String);
          let imageSrc = base64String.split(",");
          console.log("---Splitted image string----" + imageSrc[1]);
          this.src = imageSrc[1]
 });

Comment: I have url in json data. It has to be downloaded and needs to display for each of the row in list.

Comment: There is a REST service which accepts ID of the image to download. Once this service returns success response,  it returns in binary format. This I am able to convert to base64. Now, how it will download image for every url and display in the list.

Comment: i think that is very long process to fetch the image and thats why your image  is not shown in `ion-img`